# How to get unique values retrieve from Coredata iphone app?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, entities

Am not well familiar in Coredata storage. I want to save multiple data for a `single person and retrieve the data of a selected person`. Like wise i have store values in coredata table like below,

```
ID     Name    Date                 Report                  Status
1      Gopi    31 June 01.90pm      ABCD                    Y
2      Robot   27 June 2 am         hdfsdfk                 N
1      Gopi    31 June 02.00pm      fsdjk                   N
2      Robot   29 June 3am          eyrwruo                 Y
1      Gopi    1 July 3pm           rweyskd                 Y
1      Gopi    2 July 2pm           ABCD                    N
2      Robot   1 July 2.40pm        eirwierundfs            Y
3      John    2 July 10am          fewyrhhskd              Y
3      John    3 July 11am          sdkfksjfnvmnfks         N
```

In my first view controller i want to show the details like this in tableview,

```
Gopi            2 July 2pm     >
ABCD            Y 
Robot           1 July 2.40pm  >
eirwierundfs    Y
John            3 July 11am    >
sdkfksjfnvmnfks Y
```

`When the user selects Gopi, It will navigate to another view controller with table view and they can view all records of named Gopi`. And also i want to delete the selected user details from the entitiy. Can anyone please help me to get a unique user details from Coredata?

I have stored the values in coredata entity and retrieved all the rows from the entity. But, now am struggling to get a unique values of selected person data from the entity. Could you please help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: can u print error consol

Comment: I didn't get any errors. I just want to filter the data from the coredata table rows. Could please tell me how to filter the data from coredata? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While fetching  record from core data add these two lines

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Name==%@",str];
 //  Give your attribute name instead of "name"
 //  In str give the name "gopi" (for your case)  or whatever you want    

[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
//set predicate to your fetch request
```

Then execute fetch request

Comment: Mr.Dinesh thanks a lot for your answer. I will try it now itself. It is possible to delete selected user data from Coredata entity. could you please help me. Thanks.

Comment: @Gopinath Have you actually read the Apple documentation regarding CoreData? Perhaps if you read it, you would be able to answer your own questions on this... https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdCreateMOs.html

Comment: Yes you can delete the selected user data.
Fetch the object to be deleted using predicate and then delete that object

Comment: @NickBull Thanks for your help. Am started to study about the Coredata. But, now am in rush to complete it that's why i posted this question and needed help from you all. Thanks.

Comment: @DineshKaushik Thank you for your post. I will try it and let you know. Thanks.